# Installing R 3.4.0 on macOS / Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: r, installation, osx-mavericks

I would like to use the latest version of R on my Mac (running OS X 10.9). The problem is that binaries are only provided for OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and higher.

My question is: is it possible to have it running anyway on my system, and if so, is there a tutorial somewhere indicating how to do it?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: It's better for you to upgrade your system to have R 3.4.0.  Upgrading system + R binaries is the most easy option. For example, R3.4.0 needs GNU Fortran 6.1, and as far as I know, the binaries of GFortran 6.1 again requires EI Captain and higher... And you don't want to install GFortran from source on mac.

Comment: Hi @lpays ~ Have you found a solution (a better one that the one I suggest below)?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a bit of time researching the topic, for the same reason: I am currently running OS X 10.9.5, and wanted to upgrade from R 3.3.3 to R 3.4.0. However, in my view, you are better off upgrading OS X to macOS than trying to meet the [requirements to build R from source](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/):

> **Important note:** R 3.4.0 El Capitan binaries are using Clang 4.0.0 and GNU Fortran 6.1 to provide OpenMP parallelization support and C++17 standard features. If you want to compile R packages from sources, please download GNU Fortran binary from the official GNU Fortran Binaries page - in particular OS X 10.11 gfortran 6.1. We are also providing Clang 4.0.0 binaries for OS X 10.11 and higher in our libs directory (note that the offical Clang 4.0.0 binaries only support macOS 10.12) and will provide an Apple Installer package here soon.

My understanding of the above is that building recent R releases on macOS 10.11 or 10.12 is fine because that's what the core developers do on their end, whereas building on older versions of OS X is now unsupported and untested.

If I were you, I would stick to R 3.3.3 (my short-term choice), or upgrade OS X to macOS (my long-term choice). Building R on old Mac OS X versions will throw you in dependency hell, for very little (and only partial re: new features) benefit.